# How to run gtalk app with wine?

Tags: 10.04, wine, google-talk

I used to use gtalk application alot when I used Windows and I still use it at work. At home, where I use Ubuntu 10.04, I usually use pidgin or empathy for using connecting to google talk. But I dont like the interface of any of these apps. So I am looking for some help with run gtalk app with wine.

I tried installing gtalk using wine sometime ago but didnt succeed and unfortunately I dont remember the error that I got. How do I do this. Has any one succeeded in doing this.

UPDATE
I have tried installing gtalk using wine and after the setup completes and gtalk opens, I get a dialog saying "Gtalk has encoutered an internal error and needs to close. Please report this error to Google" and when I click ok on that dialog box, gtalk quits.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to help you with that rare information. I first suggest you to try it again and write down any errors when executing.

For wine it is the case, that it is very dependend on the wine version, whether a windows application works or not.

Some hints what you could try:

- run the windows application with wine from a terminal then you can see (more) error messages

  wine Foo.exe
- it might help to install the latest version of wine directly from [WineHQ.org](http://www.winehq.org)

I hope that helps to get it working, but you luck to get applications working in wine.

Another alternative would be to use the GTalk-Browser-Plugin, which is available for Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wine is not good product try to use pidgin or empathy,It is difficult to install g talk through wine as it download component while installation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend empathy for GTalk too. I used to use the GTalk app in Windows too, but empathy works very well with GTalk, even video calling works.